# Change response "not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header" in AWS ApiGateway

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've read other similar posts with exact same error message, however my question is different.

I have an AWS ApiGateway in https://XXXXXXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx/users  (from now I will call it as **`/users`** ).

I have implemented my ApiGateway to Lambda scripts with Cognito authorization, they work without problems, for example:

- **`/users/me`** -> returns data of current logged user

The problem is when I call an unexistent route in ApiGateway, for example:

- **`/users/mine123`** -> it returns

> { "message":
> "'my-cognito-user-id-token' not a
> valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header:
> 'Bearer my-cognito-user-id-token'." }

My question is... **Is there a way to return a NotFound or BadRequest error when route in ApiGateway doesn't exist?**

I think is possible implementing resource ANY, but, **is there a "clean" way to do it without resource ANY?**

---

***Edit 1:***

I tried Api Gateway response as well. I set a custom response, an status error code 404 for **Resource Not Found** but Api Gateway still returns **403 Forbidden**.

[image: Resource not found configuration]

***Edit 2***

I already have **4XX** responses configured too:

[image: Resource 4XX]

And API Gateway always returns 403 error with this message (as expected for a generic 4XX error), however I think it doesn't make sense because is not a real `Forbidden` error it's a `NotFound` or `BadRequest` error.

For example,

- A request to nonexistent route in Github API https://api.github.com/ROUTE_THAT_DOESNT_EXIST returns `404 NotFound`.
- A request to nonexistent route in StackExchange API https://api.stackexchange.com/ROUTE_THAT_DOESNT_EXIST returns `400 BadRequest`.

None of them return `403 Forbidden`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Error message `{ "message": "token not a valid key=value pair Authorization header: 'Bearer token'.` is thrown when "Resource path doesn't exist" with [status 403](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/) with a response header "x-amzn-ErrorType" = "IncompleteSignatureException"

> A request with an "Authorization" header is sent to an API resource
> path that doesn't exist.

We can customize response body in 'Gateway Response' section. There doesn't seem to specific Gateway Response like Unauthorized, Invalid Signature, etc for this scenario, Hence we need to configure `Default 4XX`

We can update `status code` and `Response Templates`. Unlike Integration Response on a successful request process, error gateway response template [doesn't support full VTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-gatewayResponse-definition.html#customize-gateway-responses) template but only supports simple place holders.

Example configuration for `application/json`

```
{"message":"Invalid Resource","type": "$context.error.responseType","stage": "$context.stage"}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Will return

```
{
    "message": "Invalid Resource",
    "type": "DEFAULT_4XX",
    "stage": "qa"
}
```

Comment: I tried that, **Resource not found** is set as 404 error, however Api Gateway still returns 403 Forbidden.

Comment: @Vlady Did you try for `Default 4XX`? `Resource not found` is for missing resource after successful authentication, ex: missing lambda function

Comment: Added screenshot with configuration I tested.

Comment: yes I did, but it's confusing, for example if I send an invalid token to a valid resource it returns `UNAUTHORIZED`, but if I send a valid or invalid token to an invalid resource it always returns `FORBIDDEN`.

Comment: `Unauthorized` is error response of coginto/custom authorizer, which results in 401 and gateway response `Unauthorized` as well. This particular case of presence of  Authentication header but invalid resource will result in `IncompleteSignatureException` and `403` as per the documentation.

Comment: so, `Unauthorized` error comes from Cognito, that means for a `NotFound` error there should be a resource that returns 404 error, right? I've read a solution implementing resource `ANY` that returns 404 error, but I don't want to do that, I want a cleaner way

Comment: If `resource` is not even present, it will return 403, it will not try to find methods GET, ANY, etc. The cleaner way and AWS recommended way is to configure gateway response and in this case we need to configure `Default 4XX` response. I have tested and it working as expected.

Comment: yes, it returns 403 and that's my question, is there a way to return `NotFound` or `BadRequest`?, for example, a request to nonexistent route in Github API https://api.github.com/route_that_doesnt_exist returns 404 NotFound, or a request to nonexistent route in StackExchange API https://api.stackexchange.com/route_that_doesnt_exist returns 400 BadRequest (with a 404 message xD ),

Comment: in your update, You configured Gateway Respone for 'Resource not found', but we should configure for 'Default 4XX' and deploy. it should work.

Comment: I did (Edit 2), but this is a generic response 4XX that API Gateway always returns 403 error and I don't want that, I want specific responses (for my case 404 NotFound)

Comment: @vlady you can change `Response status code` on the same page where you setup GatewayResponse to different response code.

Comment: then I'll get 404 error for Forbidden/BadRequest/MethodNotAllowed/etc., what a headache is AWS sometimes :(

Comment: unfortunately, there wasn't specific gateway error for Invalid Signature(I will contact AWS), but I went ahead and configured two other errors that I get  `Access Denied` (rejected policy) and `Unauthorized`(Authorizer Errors) , then it won't default to 4XX.

Comment: I think the best approach is to use everything you suggested, thanks for your help!!

Comment: @vlady I got confirmation from AWS support that there is no specific gateway response for `IncompleteSignatureException` and they will create a feature request!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it is a cleaner way than your suggestion, however you can configure specific gateway response for the missing authentication token - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-gateway-response-using-the-console.html

> In the Gateway Responses pane, choose a response type. In this walkthrough, we use Missing Authentication Token (403) as an example.

> You can change the API Gateway-generated Status Code to return a different status code that meets your API's requirements. In this example, the customization changes the status code from the default (403) to 404 because this error message occurs when a client calls an unsupported or invalid resource that can be thought of as not found.

Comment: I tried that, **Resource not found** is set as 404 error, however Api Gateway still returns 403 Forbidden.